# Set an object property by using its value

Tags: javascript

Say I call following function:

```
var query = makeQuery("email", "foo@bar.com");
```

The implementation I have is:

```
makeQuery = function (key, value) {
    return { key: value};
}
```

The object I end up with is: {"key": "foo@bar.com"}, which is obviously wrong. I would like to obtain {"email": "foo@bar.com"} instead. I tried setting it like so:

```
makeQuery = function (key, value) {
    return { JSON.stringify(key): value};
}
```

... but I get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." I've also thought of using toString() and even eval(), without success. So my problem is to be able to set the property of the object returned in makeQuery() using its real value, that is, pick up the value of 'key', not setting the property with the 'key' literal.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: myDOMElement.setAttribute("attName","attValue"); might help also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the object first and then use the square bracket syntax so you can set the property using the *value* of `key`:

```
makeQuery = function (key, value) {
    var query = {};
    query[key] = value;
    return query;
};
```

Comment: This one gets my vote because the function reads better. The other solutions work as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For variable keys in objects, use

```
var obj[key] = value
```

So then it becomes:

```
function makeQuery(key, value) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

define an object..

```
makeQuery = function (key, value) {
 var o = {};
 o[key] = value; 
 return o;
}
```